# Not quite alternating series

Tags: reference-request, power-series

Quite a lot of things are known about alternating power series
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n a_n x^n, \quad a_n > 0,
$$
like closed-form expressions for well-chosen $a_n$ and so on. In a problem I'm working on I have a series of the form
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n(n+1)/2} a_n x^n, \quad a_n > 0,
$$
where the signs go $+$ $-$ $-$ $+$ $+$ $-$ $-$ $+$ $+$... (I'd write the actual coefficients $a_n$ here if I knew them, but such is the world.)

Surely someone has looked into these kind of things and some techniques and tricks for dealing with them are out there, maybe even closed-form formulas for well-chosen $a_n$. Has anyone here seen these before?

Comment: You can just combine the two neighboring positive terms into one, then the two negative ones, and so on.  Then the alternating series theorems apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it up into two alternating power series.

Consider the values for even $n$ as one, and for odd $n$ as the other:

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}a_nx^n = \sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^{2n}a_{2n}x^{2n} + \sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^{2n+1}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: That's true and a good tip, thanks! However, I have reason to believe that each odd/even series won't make much sense on its own (these come up while calculating the square of the norm of a differential form, so I guess/hope the terms will be related to the original form), so any ideas on the series as a whole are still welcome. :)